# What is the preferred way to validate data in an AngularJS app?

Tags: angularjs, validation

I've heard of a couple of different approaches to providing the validation specs to an Angular UI.

One is to build it in on the UI side with a configuration file specifying such things as field length, which fields are required, and valid selections as examples of items to be validated.

Another approach is to have the UI query a service on the backend to provide these validations by pulling them out of a database. There is a logical grouping of validations, so the service would specify the group ID and the validations would be returned.

I can see advantages to both, but the database side may start to feel like a UI framework instead of just a set of validations. You still need to specify the endpoints for CRUD operations, but putting that in the backend would make the whole thing pretty heavy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your UI, you can use standard HTML5 attributes to validate the inputs. Client-side validation cannot alone secure user input. **Server side validation is also necessary.**

To create your own validation function you have to add a new directive to your application and deal with the validation inside a function with certain specified arguments.

Keep rocking!

Comment: Yes, I understand the need for validation on both ends. But my question is where are the constraints that are used on the client side coming from? Are they read in from a config file on the client side, or does the client side make a call to the backend to retrieve the validation constraints?